# A twisted series

Tags: steganography

Find the next number in this series:

> 503, 507, 550...

> Maybe you'd want to pay close attention to the tags

**HINT 1:**

> The maker always leaves his trademark or stamp on it.

**HINT 2**

> When you can't find the answer, look back at the source

Comment: (There don't appear to be any characters out of the ordinary in the source of this post - everything is ASCII, no zero-width characters or lookalikes or anything weird like that. And nothing weird about the source either.)

Comment: @Deusovi rot13(npghnyyl, gurer vf, nobhg gur fbhepr)

Comment: Whatever you're referring to, I don't see it - the source directly reflects what's in the post, and I copied it into a text editor so I could check for weird characters with regex.

Comment: @Deusovi, I could have justified myself, but if I do, the answer will be clear. I have already told you more than required, Sorry.

Comment: @Deusovi I don't think its weird characters, rot13(V pbhyq or jebat ohg vfa'g gurer rkprff bs punenpgre gb gur abez?) But I don't know what it means.

Comment: @Abbas rot13(lbhe jnl bs ivrjvat qbrfa'g frrz evtug).

Comment: @Quark-epoch I'm kind of glad. :P That seemed too convoluted.

Comment: This puzzle seems too difficult. I may add a hint tomorrow.

Comment: Hmm... Does that mean you will edit it? I hope you don't remove a **tag**.

Comment: as the source is involved, is it browser independet? while investigating line numbers of tags i stumbled upon it beeing totally different in different browsers. so i hope im off track.

Comment: @Abbas no I won't

Comment: @Quark-epoch you added a tag, does that not change the answer?

Comment: @Abbas No I didn't. the only tag was the steganography tag which was from the start.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the date stamp (hint 1)?

Comment: You have already asked $4-5$ [tag:steganography] questions in this site, looking at the number, is it representing your rep points when you posted them? (Am I in a right direction?)

Comment: @Duck No, not the right way to go.

Comment: @athin, Try elaborating it by posting an answer as I am not able to completely understand what you mean.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Long shot but here we go

> The next number is 557

In the OP's response in the comments,

> @Deusovi rot13(npghnyyl, gurer vf, nobhg gur fbhepr)

...

> the source refers to both 
>     a) the source of the question (the OP) and 
>     b) the source code of the web page

Following the first one by...

> visiting the OP's [profile page](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51989/quark-epoch)

we are greeted by the following message

> Look Closely See nearby 
>  Here lies the way
>  (to the next hintswer (hint+answer))
>  a puzzle is lost on this website
>  use me to know if your'e right

Following this we..

> ..click on the nearby Activity tab

On the new page we can now apply the 2nd sense of OP's comment above or by paying close attention to the...

> HTML **tags** (or source code) 
>  Doing a Ctrl+F here we can see that 503, 507, and 550 appears in code that plots the OP's reputation on a graph. 
>  However, 530 and 540 are smack in between 507 and 550. My **flimsy** theory is that the OP just hovered on the actual generated graph and missed these two values.

I know this guess is walking on thin ice but I've spent too much time not to post an answer! :P

Comment: You got it! I think the hint was too obvious. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

> Don't slate me if this is wrong but 559?  First ever puzzle attempt!

Comment: What is your reasoning behind it?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE, try answering using spoiler tags ( >! ) the next time.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: sorry i feel i need to work out exactly how to remove spoilers now first

Comment: now I have finally got the tags to work - apologies for not doing it earlier!
>! It is in your source code there is a specific tag id which is the next in the sequence

Comment: @HoneyBadger The spoiler tag (`>!`) does not work in comments. Here it is more acceptable to use https://rot13.com/ to obfuscate your comment :)

Comment: Aw thank you :) sorry I am so new to this as you can tell! Really appreciate your help